# What type of sentence is this?

Tags: sentence

I came across this sentence,

”The vibrations from the jet caused the vase to fall and crack”

I am confused on what type of sentence it is: “simple, compound, compound-complex, or complex.”

“Vibrations caused vase” doesn’t make to much sense if you simplified the sentence, so would it be “vibrations caused vase to fall and crack?”

Except, in the second example, I’m not really sure what the direct object would be, or if there is some type of object complement.

Comment: *Vibrations caused the vase* is not a simplified sentence. It's a sentence fragment. A simplified sentence would be *vibrations caused the vase to fall*. Or, to fit something into the format of the sentence fragment that is actually complete, *vibrations cracked the vase*.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Is the sentence simple, compound, compound-complex, or complex? Also, what is the direct object, and is there any object complement?

Comment: @Seeker I'm saying that the question needs to be fixed so it makes sense before we can understand what's actually being asked. We can address the sentence itself, but the question about the sentence could be caused by confusion that would be addressed by clarifying the analysis. Only the person who asked the question can clarify exactly what they think about it. (Which is required, otherwise it should be closed for a lack of research.)

Comment: It's a complex sentence since it has a main clause (the sentence as whole) and an embedded subordinate clause ("to fall and crack") functioning as complement of "caused". "The vase" is direct object of "caused", but it's not part of the subordinate clause.

Comment: @BillJ I think I'm getting a better understanding of finite and non finite clauses, but why is "to fall and crack" an embedded subordinate clause? Are "embedded subordinate clauses" supposed to be in the middle of the sentence? Also is it a non finite clause? I thought embedded clauses did not have infinitives. Thanks

Comment: Subordinate clauses can be of any kind -- there is no general restriction, and they can pop up anywhere in a sentence, subject of course to the structure of the clause and context etc.

Comment: Okay, I just researched what an embedded clause is, and it said that they usually are in the middle of the sentence, and there are two types of them: "nominal and relative." I don't know how accurate this is.

Comment: Please read my last comment.

Comment: I've read it, but I still have one question. Is there a difference between an embedded subordinate and subordinate clause? Sorry if I'm asking a lot of questions, this is all very new to me since I was taught trad grammar.

Comment: And you're saying that "to fall and crack" is a subordinate clause, right? A non finite clause?